# Querystring value being stripped from site_url()

Tags: site-url, query-string

This is a question about a plugin.

A form to search the database works.  What I am trying to do is have the search term reload into the form input field when returning search results.  The problem is strange and appears to be something to do with `site_url()`

I am setting a variable `$search_url = site_url( 'wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin&action=search&searchstringSO=' . $_REQUEST["sigsearch"]  );`  which is the URL that is loaded with my results. Note the `SO` at the end of the key, that is a debug flag so I know I am looking at the right URL - I am.

The resulting URL is `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin&action=search&searchstringSO&_wpnonce=8664768fcc` notice the `=` and the search string are missing.

I am pretty good at trouble shooting and can't find where it is being stripped.

Things I have tried:

- displaying the value of `$_REQUEST["sigsearch"]` right before creating the `$search_url` variable - it works
- loading the URL string into it's own variable (which works) and then passing that to `site_url()`
- adding `&dummy=0` at the end - that also works

For some reason the querystring value (which is nothing more than a text string) plus the `=`  are stripped out of the URL.

Is this a quirk of `site_url()` or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: How are you performing the search? Why do you even need to build this URL? If you have a search form then won't submitting it lead to the correct URL?  I don't really understand why you need to populate the search term into the URL yourself.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I adopted an abandoned plugin so I have no idea why it was done the way it was originally.  Adding something like a search function is tricky as I work my way through someone else's code.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using `admin_url` instead of `site_url` you can call it the same way, but as you are trying to fetch some admin page I think that might be a better idea.

`$search_url = admin_url( '/admin.php?page=my-plugin&action=search&searchstringSO=' . $_REQUEST["sigsearch"]  );`

Note that I removed the `wp-admin` prefix from the path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The URL still doesn't contain that pesky value.  But I didn't know about admin_url so +1

Comment: How about your `siteurl` value in `wp_options` does it contain anything strange? You could also check if you have any hook for the `site_url`, `default_option_siteurl`, or `pre_option_siteurl` filter.